# Cohomological field theories and Q operator

Tags: gauge-theory, supersymmetry, topological-field-theory

In cohomological field theories we have nilpotent $Q$ operator and one can define Lagrangian as $L=[Q,V]$ and energy momentum tensor $T_{\alpha \beta} = [Q,G_{\alpha \beta}]$. So these quantities are defined as commutators (or anti commutators) of some operators with Q. One also has this relation $\delta_{\epsilon} \mathcal{O}= i\epsilon[Q,\mathcal{O}]$.

My question is: If someone gave me a Lagrangian or energy-momentum tensor for the cohomological field theory how would I proceed to find the operator $Q$ and/or the other two operators $V$ and $G_{\alpha \beta}$ ? Is this possible without guessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to guess (or rather, choose).  The Lagrangian does not uniquely determine $Q$.  In fact, there are Lagrangians (with appropriately corresponding supersymmetric QFTs) which admits continuous families of Qs.  N=4 SYM is one example.

$V$ and $G_{\alpha\beta}$ are only determined up to $Q$-commutators.  Another choice here.

More generally, I don't think there's an algorithm to find all of the symmetries of some class of a given Lagrangian.

Comment: Can you point me to a reference where this family of operators is derived in  N=4 SYM ?

Comment: It's discussed in Kapustin & Witten,  Electric-Magnetic Duality And The Geometric Langlands Program, https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0604151 .